# How to create a custom dialog

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I need to create yes/no confirmation dialog in a foreign language. I think I need to create my own class by extending Dialog ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this should do the trick. My apologies to any Swedish chefs watching.

```
int answer = Dialog.ask("Gersh gurndy morn-dee burn-dee, burn-dee, flip-flip-flip-flip-flip-flip-flip-flip-flip?", new String[] {"Hokey dokey","Bork bork bork"}, new int[] {Dialog.OK,Dialog.CANCEL}, Dialog.CANCEL);
```

Edits:

```
The above explained better: 
public final static int NEGATIVE = 0;
public final static int AFIRMATIVE = 1;
public final static int DEFAULT = NEGATIVE;
int answer = Dialog.ask("question?", new String[] {"afirmative button label", "negative button label"}, new int[] {AFIRMATIVE,NEGATIVE}, DEFAULT);
```

As you can see from the above it is possible to change all the text (language) values on a Dialog just by using this method so you shouldn't need a custom class to create a Dialog in another language.

It's even simpler if you use the standard BB localizing approach the simpler method (Dialog.ask(res.getString(SOMEQUESTION)) will automatically have it's afirmative and negative buttons adjusted for the language set in the phones options. You will only need to add the question as a string resource.

You can find a list of valid methods and constructors here:
http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Dialog.html

More Edits below:

I thought my above answer was what you were after but if you do need to further customize the dialog in a new class you may do it like this:

```
public class MyDialogScreen extends MainScreen implements LocalResource {

    private int exitState;

    ...

    protected void sublayout( int width, int height ) {
        setExtent( dialogWidth, dialogHeight );
        setPosition( XPOS, YPOS );
        layoutDelegate( dialogWidth, dialogHeight );
    }

    // do some stuff and assign exitState appropriately
    // e.g. a button that sets exitState = 1 then pops this screen
    // another button that sets exitState = 2 then pops this screen
    ...  

    public int getExitState() 
    {
        return this.exitState;
    }
```

In the above I've created a new screen and I have overridden the sublayout method to specify a custom width, height and xy positions in layoutDelegate. When you push this screen you will see it as a dialog like box above the previous screen on the stack at the XY positions you specified.

Make sure to use pushModal. This will allow you to access the getExitState method after the screen has been popped from the display stack.

E.g

```
MyDialogScreen dialog = new MyDialogScreen();
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushModalScreen(dialog);
int result = dialog.getExitState();
```

Cheers

Ray